# Android NDK gradle setting

Tags: android-ndk

I have an problem
My gradle setting

### build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hanium.project.androidapp_picturehawk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /*
     * native build settings: taking default for almost everything
     */
    ndk {
        moduleName = 'hello-jni'
        toolchain = 'clang'
        CFlags.addAll(['-Wall'])
    }

    productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {`enter code here`
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

build.gradle(Project:~)
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

----------------------------------------------
but i have an error

Error:(24, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ndk()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'AndroidApp_PictureHawk' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.`enter code here`
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

what should I do??
please help me

Answer (score 2):

Read your error message!

```
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'AndroidApp_PictureHawk' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.`enter code here`
```

Then look for and remove `enter code here`:

```
productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {`enter code here`
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
```